go func() and time.Sleep(changeableDuration * second) combine invalidates BlockInput(false)
Object
I want to write a program that can block input from both keyboard and mouse with golang. However, there is a problem that I can only block input but cannot retrieve it when I use go func(). I want to know the reason. I would appreciate it If there are any solutions.
The error code
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var (
    user32         = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procBlockInput = user32.NewProc("BlockInput")
)

func BlockInput(block bool) bool {
    var blockValue uintptr
    if block {
        blockValue = 1
    } else {
        blockValue = 0
    }

    ret, _, _ := procBlockInput.Call(blockValue)
    return ret != 0
}
func main() {
    // fmt.Println("Starting block...")

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Starting block...")
        success := BlockInput(true)
        fmt.Println("BlockInput(true) success: ", success)

        defer BlockInput(false)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        success = BlockInput(false)
        fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) success: ", success)

        if !success {
            err := syscall.GetLastError()
            fmt.Printf("BlockInput(false) failed with error: %v\n", err) // success == false, but err == nil
        } else {
            fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) succeeded")
        }

        fmt.Println("Done!")
    }()
    // BlockInput(true)

    // defer BlockInput(false)

    // testDuration := 5
    // time.Sleep(time.Duration(testDuration) * time.Second)

    // BlockInput(false)

    // fmt.Println("Done!")

    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("exit!")

    // os.Exit(0)
}

The error output
error output
// output
Starting block...
BlockInput(true) success: true
BlockInput(false) success: false
BlockInput(false) failed with error: <nil>
Done!

The success code
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var (
    user32         = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procBlockInput = user32.NewProc("BlockInput")
)

func BlockInput(block bool) bool {
    var blockValue uintptr
    if block {
        blockValue = 1
    } else {
        blockValue = 0
    }

    ret, _, _ := procBlockInput.Call(blockValue)
    return ret != 0
}
func main() {

    // go func() {
    //  fmt.Println("Starting block...")
    //  success := BlockInput(true)
    //  fmt.Println("BlockInput(true) success: ", success)

    //  defer BlockInput(false)
    //  time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    //  success = BlockInput(false)
    //  fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) success: ", success)

    //  if !success {
    //      err := syscall.GetLastError()
    //      fmt.Printf("BlockInput(false) failed with error: %v\n", err)
    //  } else {
    //      fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) succeeded")
    //  }

    //  fmt.Println("Done!")
    // }()

    fmt.Println("Starting block...")
    success := BlockInput(true)
    fmt.Println("BlockInput(true) success: ", success)

    defer BlockInput(false)

    testDuration := 5
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(testDuration) * time.Second)

    success = BlockInput(false)
    fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) success: ", success)

    if !success {
        err := syscall.GetLastError()
        fmt.Printf("BlockInput(false) failed with error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("BlockInput(false) succeeded")
    }

    fmt.Println("Done!")

    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("exit!")

    // os.Exit(0)
}

The success output
success output
// output
Starting block...
BlockInput(true) success: true
BlockInput(false) success: true
BlockInput(false) succeeded
Done!


Can anyone tell the reason?
I would appreciate it If there are any solutions.

The return vals of procBlockInput.Call(blockValue)

...
// success return
ret1: 1, ret2: 0, err: The operation completed successfully.
...
// fail return
ret1: 0, ret2: 0, err: The operation completed successfully.


Isn't the error returned by  procBlockInput.Call(blockValue) somehow usefull ?

No, the error message returned by procBlockInput.Call(blockValue)  is  The operation completed successfully even when the first return is 0.
